# Java - Streaming Linear Regression

Tags: java, stream, linear-regression

I am working on a project in Java that involves fitting a simple linear regression line through a **rolling** / **sliding** window of n data points. For each new point added the linear regression slope and intercept need to be re-calculated. We currently use `org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression` to do this calculation, but it is expensive to re-calculate the entire window each time.

So I have two questions.

1. The `SimpleRegression` offered by apache commons has a removeData method for use in a "streaming mode". (See quotation below taken from [API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html)). However there is no other information on this "streaming mode"; proper implementation,accumulative error, etc... Does anyone have an example of how to use it properly in streaming mode? or can anyone point me to a better source of information?

> "This method permits the use of SimpleRegression instances in streaming   mode where the regression is applied to a sliding "window" of observations, however the caller is responsible for maintaining the set of observations in the window.
>   "

2. Are there any other libraries available that can do **streaming** linear regression in constant time? Surely Apache Commons SimpleRegression is not the only one... but that seems to be the only one I can find...

Thanks,
g

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code I suppose this only means there is the method **removeData** which reverses the calculations done by addData. So the caller has to remember the data in the window and remove it one by one when the data "exits" the window.